# How can I assign a variable of type interfaceA with a method that returns a broader interface, to a variable of type interfaceB with narrower return

Tags: go, interface, return-type

First time posting a question here, sorry if the format is wrong. Do let me know how I could improve my question asking.

```golang
package main

type smallerInterface interface {
    Problem() smallerRet
}

type biggerInterface interface {
    Problem() biggerRet
}

type smallerRet interface {
    Wait() bool
}

type biggerRet interface {
    Wait() bool
    Error() error
}

type ret struct{}

type sample struct{}

func (ret) Wait() bool {
    return true
}

func (ret) Error() error {
    return nil
}

func (sample) Problem() biggerRet {
    return ret{}
}
    

func main() {
    var first biggerInterface = sample{}
    var second smallerInterface = sample{}
}
```

Demo of the problem can be viewed here https://play.golang.org/p/l0xdO03bBy7

Basically, is there a way to reconcile both `smallerInterface` and `biggerInterface` so `sample` can be assigned to a variable of type `smallerInterface`?

Concretely I would like to use `smallerInterface` for mocking in internal testing and receive `biggerInterface` from an external library in producton. As such it would be preferable to keep the `smallerRet` interface so I can keep the mock return value interface small, with sample being the production return value.

Additionally, is there a name for this problem or concept?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: dnt change the signature of your apis for your tests. Use `smallerRet`, within your tests add a type assertion to verify it implements an `interface{Error()error}` and call it if it does.

Comment: @mh-cbon The thing is I cannot use smallerRet for everything since biggerInterface is what is implemented in the package and I am trying to make a narrower interface that consumes the biggerInterface value from the package, since in my program I only need Wait()

In real world context this would be a difference of say 7+ methods which does make an impact on readability and I would guess safety

Answer (score 0):

You can try embedding the interfaces so that the sample can be assigned to type `smallerInterface`. I recreated your code as follows :

```
package main

import "fmt"

type smallerInterface interface {
    biggerInterface
}

type biggerInterface interface {
    Problem() biggerRet
}

type smallerRet interface {
    Wait() bool
}

type biggerRet interface {
    Wait() bool
    Error() error
}

type ret struct{}

type sample struct{}

func (ret) Wait() bool {
    return true
}

func (ret) Error() error {
    return nil
}

func (sample) Problem() biggerRet {
    return ret{}
}

func main() {
    var first biggerInterface = sample{}
    var second smallerInterface = sample{}

    fmt.Println(first)
    fmt.Println(second)
}
```

Output:

```
{}
{}
```

Comment: I suppose that is a solution but the issue I have with that is I am now forced to implement biggerRet for the return value in smallerInterface which does circumvent the issue but results in the use of an excessively broad interface if my sample could make do with smallerRet. This also makes the creation of the smallerInterface moot

In context my mock sample which could have used smallerInterface would now need to return a mock biggerRet instead of smallerRet, which would require a pointless Error() method in this case and like 8 pointless methods in my real world usecase